# Derivative of double integral with respect to symmetric limits

Tags: integration, derivatives

How do I find the following?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-x}^x \int_{-x}^x f(y,z) \;dy\; dz$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the derivative is
$$\int_{-x}^x f(y,x)\,dy-(-1)\int_{-(-x)}^{-x} f(y,-x)\,dy.$$
If we make the change of variable $t=-x$ in the second integral, we get
$$\int_{-t}^{t} (-1)f(y,t)\,dy.$$
This cancels the first integral.